# Oracle table and number of blocks

Tags: oracle

What is the easiest way of finding out the number of blocks a table (oracle) occupies and the number of extents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there are no LOB fields or other specialties:

```
select sum(blocks) as blocks, count(*) as extents 
from dba_extents
where owner = '&table_owner' and segment_name = '&table_name';
```

Comment: Another option is to query the dba_segments view.